# Conditional Retrieval

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing lengthy query that retrieves something like this (made it look shorter).

```
Field1 Field2 Key
------ ------ --- 
R      NULL   2
T      CAF21  2
R      NULL   1
R      NULL   3
```

Scenario: 
`R` row may not always have a `T` row. But if `T` row exists for each key, the `T` row will be used.

I am supposed to display only the `T` rows for each `Key` data.
However, if `T` does not exists for the `Key`, I'm supposed to display the `R` data.

How can I achieve this through a query?

Expected output:

> Condition 1: I'll retrieve those `Key` that has `T` existing

```
 Field1 Field2 Key
 ------ ------ ---
 T      CAF21  2
```

> Condition 2: I'll retrieve those `Key` that has `R` only

```
 Field1 Field2 Key
 ------ ------ ---
 R      NULL   3
 R      NULL   1
```

Comment: Can you please put up the 'expected output' in suitable format?

Comment: Answer will differ depending on your data and expected result. So provide more sample data including most of your possible scenarios and expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE `ROW_NUMBER` with `Partition By` as below:

You have to play with below two fields for your requirement and apply where condition as required:

```
RANK() OVER (Partition BY keyvalue order by CASE field1 WHEN 'T' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS PartNo,
CASE field1 WHEN 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS fieldValue;
```

Whole Query:

```
DECLARE @tblQuestion AS Table
(
    field1 varchar(20),
    field2 VARCHAR(50),
    keyvalue INT
)

INSERT INTO @tblQuestion VALUES('R',NULL,2)
INSERT INTO @tblQuestion VALUES('T','CAFR',2)
INSERT INTO @tblQuestion VALUES('R',NULL,1)
INSERT INTO @tblQuestion VALUES('R',NULL,3)


;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT 
        field1,
        field2,
        keyvalue,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY keyvalue order by CASE field1 WHEN 'T' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS PartNo,
       CASE field1 WHEN 'T' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS fieldValue
    FROM @tblQuestion
)

SELECT 
    *
FROM T
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: How can I use my existing query in it?

Comment: I have used your tabel

Comment: Thank you fiddling with it now.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is by using a `UNION`

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, KEY
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE FIELD1 = 'T'
UNION
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, KEY
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE KEY NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT KEY FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE FIELD1 = 'T');
```